# I have a problem with applying backspace with python

Tags: python

So I have recorded my keystrokes, which looks like this (just an example):

**keystrokes.txt**:

```
[23:43 30/04/2023]: delete(alt)(tab)(alt)(tab)(tab)
[23:47 30/04/2023]: left windows i n(backspace)(backspace)(backspace)(alt)(tab)(alt)(tab) b i t . l y / i n s k
[23:47 30/04/2023]: s t r [ y(backspace)(backspace)(backspace) r p y(enter)(alt)(tab)(alt)(tab)
[23:47 30/04/2023]: (alt)(tab)(tab)(tab)(tab)(alt)(tab)(alt)(tab)(alt)(tab)(alt)(tab)
```

As you can see it's a bit confusing reading it with the (backspace) thing right? Then I want to convert this `keyst.txt` file to a new one with the (backspace) really acting as a backspace, so I created a Python code to convert it but it did not go as I wanted.

This is my **convert.py**:

```
# Read the contents of the file
with open('keystrokes.txt', 'r') as file:
    text = file.read()

# Replace "(backspace)" with the backspace character and "(space)" with a space character
text = text.replace('(backspace)', '\b').replace('(space)', ' ')

# Print the updated text
print(text, file="converted.txt")
```

But it just gave me this:

```
[23:43 30/04/2023]: delete(alt)(tab)(alt)(tab)(tab)
[23:47 30/04/2023]: left windows i n(alt)(tab)(alt)(tab) b i t . l y / i n s k
[23:47 30/04/2023]: s t r [ y r p y(enter)(alt)(tab)(alt)(tab)
[23:47 30/04/2023]: (alt)(tab)(tab)(tab)(tab)(alt)(tab)(alt)(tab)(alt)(tab)(alt)(tab)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What happened when you ran *print(text, file="converted.txt")* ? Also, what is your expected output?

Comment: Open the updated file with notepad++ or any text viewer/editor that shows unprintable character. They may be here, but may not be able to see them;

Comment: What happens if you actually print the converted text, like `print(text)`?

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
text = text.replace('(backspace)', '\\b').replace('(space)', '\s')
```